# View binding undefined - Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

So I have an interesting issue. I have a sidebar, SortableStopView, that extends CollectionView where I have a scrollable, sortable list of 'stops' a user can click to get to that stop's summary page.

There is also SortableStopsController, an ArrayController used to sort the stops by `display_order`. In hindsight, this ArrayController isn't necessary, but I don't believe that to be my issue here.

```
App.SortableStopController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
    sortProperties: ['display_order']
    loaded: false
    stopsMoved: false

    observeStuff: (->
      console.log 'stops', @get 'content'
      console.log 'loaded', @get 'loaded'
    ).observes 'loaded', 'content'
```

Now, in StopsIndexRoute, I have `configController`. (All of my routes extend `App.AuthenticatedRoute` which overrides `setupController`, runs some custom code, and then calls `configController`. It's what I used instead of `setupController` throughout the app.) Here I set the content of SortableStopController to the stops I fetch via Ember Data and tell the controller that that data has been loaded.

```
App.StopsIndexRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend
    configController: (controller, model) ->
    self = this

    sortableStopCtlr = @controllerFor 'sortableStop'

    @store.find('stop', route_id: model.get("route_id")).then (stops) ->
        sortableStopCtlr.set 'model', stops
        sortableStopCtlr.set 'loaded', true
```

This all gets inserted into `stops.hbs` (it needs to be on all stops routes) with

```
{{view "sortableStop" content=controllers.sortableStop.arrangedContent loadedBinding="controllers.sortableStop.loaded" movedBinding="controllers.sortableStop.stopsMoved"}}
```

The issue is that the following observer logs out `this is loaded undefined`. The same follows if I log out `content`.

```
App.SortableStopView = Ember.CollectionView.extend
    observeLoaded: (->
        console.log 'this is loaded', @get 'loaded'
    ).observes 'loaded'
```

It's not shown here, but StopsController, StopsIndexController, and StopsEditController all has 'sortableStop' in their `needs` array.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of Ember, your observers aren't firing until after your controller is fully set up.  To fix it, add `on('init')` to your observer:

```
observeLoaded: (->
  console.log 'this is loaded', @get 'loaded'
).observes('loaded').on('init')
```

Comment: Yeah I looked for that. Turns out not to be the case here. Thanks, though.

This works when I come from another route that contains this view and sets the data in SortableStopController.